# How to execute a rails db query immediately?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to find some old models, create some new ones, and delete the old ones if the save was successful.

Here is my code (I apologize if it's not very Rails-y):

```
# find the old pages that are in my book... if my new pages save, delete these
old_pages = Page.where(:book_id => params['pages']['page0']['book_id'])


error_with_page_save = false

params['pages'].each do |t|
  t.each do |k|
    book_id = k['book_id']
    if k['page_type']
      tt = get_page_type_id(k['page_type'])
      page = Page.new do |t|
        t.book_id = k['book_id']
        t.sample_text = URI.decode(k['sample_text'])
        t.page_position = k['page_position']
        t.page_type_id = tt
        t.regex = URI.decode(k['regex'])
      end
      unless page.save!
        # HAD AN ISSUE SAVING ONE OF THE NEW PAGES
        error_with_page_save = true
      end
    end
  end
end

unless error_with_page_save
  puts "if there were no issues, delete all the old ones"
  old_pages.delete_all
end
```

The issue is, this deletes the new ones since the find method is not actually called until the delete.

How do I get the '.where' method to actually execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save off the ids. This has the benefit of consuming fewer resources if the dataset is large.

```
old_page_ids = Page.where(:book_id => params['pages']['page0']['book_id']).pluck(:id)
# ...
Page.where(id: old_page_ids).delete_all
```

Comment: Ha, I was just looking this up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

call `.all` on the end - this is considered to be a "final" and will make the query execute right now

Comment: Thanks! Is there a better way to do this anyway... like a rollback function?

Comment: define 'better' ;) perhaps you want to put it in a transaction in case something fails???

Comment: 'On the end,' like old_pages = Page.where(:book_id => params['pages']['page0']['book_id']).all

Comment: ok, now I'm confused... what do you mean by a rollback function then and why would you need it?

Comment: "on the end" doesn't match to "better" for me

Comment: I mean your answer says on the end. I was trying to figure out where to call it.

Comment: ah right - sorry yes that's what I meant. :) on the end of your `where` statement. I thought you were referencing my reply to your first comment.